# How to make textbox onBlur event fire dynamically on Button click

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am having a `gridview` where I had a `Copy` button when I click on that I would like to make my `javascript` event which was written for a `Textbox` `blur` event ..

My sample script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function f(txt) {
            alert("hi");
        }
    </script>
```

This I will call where ever required while looping the grid view as follows

`curTexbox.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "return f('" + curTexbox.ClientID + "'");`

This will work when I lose the focus from Textbox, But is it possible to make text box lose focus on button click and fire that event I required

Comment: Does the copy button perform a post back? In that case you would have to make the call to the script function in the click handler of the button and then perform the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
curTexbox.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "document.getElementById('buttonId').click();");
```

Comment: But where should I call my function in this

Comment: It is not calling function. Just clicks button. If you want to do it in your function, put `document.getElementById('buttonId').click();` line into your function.